# Entity Framework6 Visual Studio 2015 Mysql Problems

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, visual-studio-2015, ef-database-first

I have a problem with adding a ADO.Net Entity Data Model to my Project.
I am using VS 2015 and the Project runs with .NET 4.5.2.
The database I'm currently using is mysql.

I can connect Visual Studio with my database, which means that the connector is working and everything is installed correctly.

When I add the ADO Model and choose DB first, the following windows opens.
[image: Selecting DB for Entity Data Model]

So  I can choose a DB and everything, **but when I click next the next window can be seen for like a half a second and then it closes without any notification and no ADO.NET file or anything is created.**
I could read for a second, that there is just a radio box with the version to select. (But no red error message as in other posts mentioned)

Any ideas why that is happening? Is VS2015 not supported by EF6?

Comment: What happens when you try to add a new connection? What Data Connections can you select?

Comment: @ the moment it's where I've been too.
If have installed Mysql voor vs 1.2.4.
And references the .net 6.9.7. mysql.data, mysql.data.entity.ef6 and mysql.web.
Everthing works fine, but like Micheal, the last screen sold create , and that doesn't happen..
Win10, vs 2015

Comment: @Juanvan . Both so mssql and mysql.

Comment: I don't known how, but it seems to be solved. What I did: installed mysql for visual studio 1.2.4 and .net connector 6.9.7.
Vs 2015 new project. Menu Tools -> nuget package manager -> manage nuget package for solution. Installed entity framework, mysql.data, mysql.data.entity,  mysql.data.entities, mysql.web.
looked if alle versions match with the web.config version numbers 
build the solution. Tried and tried again. By closing VS 2015, big error about a parameter. Taskmanager to close it. Restarted pc, tried again, and how it came, it worked. I did all this more then ones. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it using MySql Installer. Try to install it, and choose MySql for Visual Studio full instalattion. After that, install Connector/NET.